# Translation of 「項目」in the company president's speech

Tags: translation

What could be the appropriate translation of the word 「項目」in the next sentence?

> 私｛わたし｝から皆様｛みなさま｝に再度｛さいど｝お願い｛おねがい｝したいことは、次｛つぎ｝８つの項目｛こうもく｝についてです。
>   
> ① <...>
>   
> ② <...>
>   
> …
>   
> ⑧ <...>

I translated it on my own as:

> I would like to ask you again to follow the directions mentioned in
>   the next 8 points: 
>   
> ① <...>
>   
> ② <...>
>   
> …
>   
> ⑧ <...>

But as for me, neither "points", "items" nor "categories" are suitable in the English version...

Answer (score 2):

I can see nothing wrong if you translated this 項目 as *points*. Is it unnatural?

The more literal translation of this sentence would be:

> What I would like to ask you again are the following 8 points.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I am not a native speaker, so I can be wrong.

Comment: As a native speaker of English, "items" seemed the best but "points" seems perfectly fine. Either can be used in a speech...